# Do we always detect cycle in an undirected graph by converting into a bidirectional directed graph

Tags: algorithm

I saw the ways of detecting cycle in an undirected graph are mostly regard as a bidirectional directed graph:

```
a-b = a->b && b->a
```

Is that the standard way? Or are there any simply ways?

Here is the code for detecting cycle in a directed graph. Here `node` is the number of nodes: `0,1,..., node-1`; `pairs[i] = {a,b}` means the string connecting a and b with direction `a->b`.

```
bool NoCyc(int node, vector<vector<int>> paris) {
    vector<vector<int>> graph(node, vector<int>());
    vector<int> visit(node);
    for (auto a : paris) {
        graph[a[1]].push_back(a[0]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < node; ++i) {
        if (!NoCyc(graph, visit, i)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool NoCyc(vector<vector<int>>& graph, vector<int>& visit, int i) {
    if (visit[i] == -1) return false;
    if (visit[i] == 1) return true;
    visit[i] = -1;
    for (auto a : graph[i]) {
        if (!NoCyc(graph, visit, a)) return false; 
    }
    visit[i] = 1;
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I found this way is wrong since single string between two nodes will be regard as a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the undirected graph you can split the graph to connected components (e.g with dfs, bfs). If one of the components edge count is not nodes - 1 then it contains cycles. (otherwise the edge count is nodes -1 what is a tree)
In undirected graph you can use this https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/finding-cycle.html algorithm.